# C++ stream iomanip equivalent to sprintf "%5.3f"

Tags: c++, stringstream

I am trying to convert an sprintf statement into C++ stream statement.
The sprintf formatting statement I am trying to replicate is "%5.3f"

I am using namespace std and have included  and

I have:

```
double my_double = GetMyDoubleFromSomewhere();

stringstream ss;

ss << ??? << my_double;
```

I have been looking at the fixed and setprecision, but can't quite figure out how to set the 5 and the 3 of the original formatting specifier?

Comment: `ss << std::setwidth(5) << std::setprecision(3)`?

Comment: @MarkShevchenko No, that's not it: you would get `"  123"` for `123.45678` instead of `"123.567"`.

Comment: Personally I'm lazy and use [boost.format](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/format/index.html)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight "123.456" is a "%7.3", not "%5.3". It's corrent to use nubmers 0.000..9.000 for "%5.3". But I forgot about `fixed`, of course.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`setprecision` and `setw` would help you.
Don't forget including `iomanip`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  using namespace std;
  double target = 1.2345;

  cout << fixed << setw(5) << setprecision(3) << target << endl;;
  printf("%5.3f\n", target);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the io manipulators `std::setw` and `std::setprecision`, something like:

```
ss << std::setw(5) << std::setprecision(3) << my_double;
```